# Does the medium matter when calculating Optical Period?

Tags: electromagnetism

If I consider the optical period $T$ for a given wavelength $\lambda$ in vacuum, I can calculate it as:
$$
T = \frac{1}{f} = \frac{\lambda}{c}
$$

However, in a particular material/medium, I am not quite sure of the following: 
*Is the optical period the same as in a vacuum or is it affected by the material properties?*

In, say silicon, I feel that I should calculate it like this:
$$
T = \frac{\lambda}{c_{Si}} = \frac{\lambda n_{Si}}{c}
$$
Is that correct or is it the first equation that prevails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T=1/f$ still holds true.   But the next part needs modification: $T=n\lambda/c$.

The frequency doesn't change.   The material changes the length of a wave.

Comment: so, you mean that the right term in my second equation is correct, only in the interpretation of the physics I must be careful not to think that the frequency is affected, only the wavelength is. Is that right?

Comment: That's correct.